# Missing artifact org.apache.commons.lang3.time:DateUtils:jar:2.0

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I always get this error in Maven and I am not sure why:

> Missing artifact org.apache.commons.lang3.time:DateUtils:jar:2.0

Here is the code in pom.xml, can somebody help me?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons.lang3.time</groupId>
         <artifactId>DateUtils</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct dependency(appropriate `groupId` and `artifactId`) to use is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> 
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

where `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils` is actually the complete class name to be used in your java class mostly like :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;
```